# How to forward all url to a single url in yii

Tags: yii

i need to know How to **forward all url** to a single url in yii
 all link go to a single url
need this for showing maintenance message

Comment: be specific what do you want?

Comment: need to catch all request and forward to one view file

Comment: add a sigle line of code in: protected/config/main.php
return array(
'catchAllRequest'=>file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/.
maintenance')
&& !(isset($_COOKIE['secret']) &&
$_COOKIE['secret']=="password") ?
array('maintenance/index') : null,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

The old code sample stopped working since Yii 1.1.16. Thanks to JamesG (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576752/how-to-forward-all-url-to-a-single-url-in-yii/12653088#comment45235781_12653088)) for the new solution. Code sample has been updated.

---

As you have already figured out, `catchAllRequest` is the best way to do this from within yii. It has been made specifically for such cases, as is quite evident from the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#catchAllRequest-detail). Using it could also probably give you a slight performance increase (over `urlManager`), but i doubt that it'll be noticeable.

On the other hand if you wish to use `urlManager`, you can try with (also read comments in code sample):

1. Version 1.1.16 and above:

   ```
   '<url:(.*)>'=>'maintenance/index'
   ```
2. Version 1.1.15 and below:

   ```
   '<url:(.*)>'=>'maintenance/index'

   // '(.*)'=>'maintenance/index' // this used to work in previous versions ...
   // of Yii (below 1.1.16) mainly due to a bug, see notes
   ```

Note: This will have to be the first rule in your urlManager's `rules` array configuration.

However as already mentioned by sl4mmer, htaccess or server configuration is the best way to do this, since the server after all catches the request first before sending it to php.

---

Note for Bug:
Check github issue [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/2945).

Comment: raghulrnair, sorry to say but the url rule mentioned by sl4mmer is incorrect for this situation, it'll only redirect visits to your baseUrl, i.e xyz.com/index.php will be redirected to somepage.html, but xyz.com/index.php/site/contact will not be redirected to somepage.html, to do that you'll have to use my format.

Comment: It seems that ````'(.*)'=>'maintenance/index'```` doesn't work any more - perhaps due to a Yii 1.1.16 update. However, wrapping the regex in a param token does work: ````'<url:(.*)>'=>'maintenance/index'````.

Comment: @JamesG i will test your suggestion and update answer accordingly, once i get some free time.

Comment: @JamesG, thanks, you were absolutely right with the change, and i have updated the answer to reflect that. Also, i managed to track down the bug which lead to the changes, and resulting fix in Yii 1.1.16, you can follow the github issue link in the answer to check that.

Answer (score 0):

You have at last two options:

- use `.htaccess` rewrite rule
- use Yii's `urlManager`'s rule with pattern matching any URL.

First option is recommended, because it is handled by server itself, it does not even touch Yii or PHP and therefore has better performance and is better secured from possible security breaks.

Comment: can u explain the 2nd method with example

Comment: 'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '/'=>'/somepage.html',
            ),
        ),