# Redirect users in every request to a single page Yii2

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, yii, yii2

So, i'm using Yii2 in my project, i've created a page(landing page), and i need to redirect all users only to this page from every single request.
Example - myblog.local - my main page, where landing page is situated. If user want to go myblog.local/lalala for example, he should be redirected to myblog.local. So he should always be in the landing page. So the question is : how can i do it? Or its better to do it from .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Copy the following to your .htaccess file:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$

RewriteRule (.*) / [R=302,L]

- You may want to exclude file extensions for stylesheets, images, and scripts from the redirection so that they can still be used by the page you are redirecting to, but I'm not sure if your setup requires that. *

Answer (score 0):

In config/main.php:

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<url:(.*)>'=>'maintenance/index',
        ],         
    ],
],
```

Reference:
[Found the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576752/how-to-forward-all-url-to-a-single-url-in-yii)