# Redirect everything to specific page, except for some URLs - Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii2

In my web app, I need to redirect **all** URLs to a specific page, with the exception of 3 specific URLs.

How can I do it globally (and painlessly) in Yii Framework? Is there a base controller I can use to handle all GET requests?

I'm using Yii 2.0.

Comment: Looking for [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#default-route) ?

Comment: Looks workable. But can I use `catchAll` to catch all requests, except for 3 URL paths?

Comment: Also, the app has lots of named routes set and the default route is employed on "empty routes" only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use this or similar UrlManager configuration:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'rules' => [
        // your rule for specific URL #1,
        // your rule for specific URL #2,
        // your rule for specific URL #3,
        '<controler>/<action>' => 'redirect/target',
    ],
]
```

This way everything that is not matched by first 3 rules is matched by the last one and goes to `'redirect/target'`.

Comment: A colleague of mine pointed out, that this kind of operation is better to be done on .htaccess level. I'm not sure if I agree with that, but the answer above definitely successfully addresses the problem I had.

Answer (score 2):

In config/main.php:

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller>/<action1>'=>'<redirect>/<target1>',
            '<controller>/<action2>'=>'<redirect>/<target2>',
            '<controller>/<action3>'=>'<redirect>/<target3>',
            '<url:(.*)>'=>'maintenance/index',
        ],         
    ],
],
```

Reference:
[Found the solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576752/how-to-forward-all-url-to-a-single-url-in-yii)

Answer (score 0):

The rules below will redirect all 3
`/exception{i}/bar/foo`
urls to the *exception* page, while redirecting everything else to the *specific* page.

```
'urlManager' => [
    'rules' => [
        '<url:(exception1.*|exception2.*|exception3.*)>' => '/path/to/3/exceptions/page',
        '<url:(.*)>' => '/path/to/specific/page',
    ],
],
```

The order matters. The exceptions must come *before* the generic rule.